# Type of correlation between binary and ordinal variable

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, binary-data, ordinal-data, pearson-r

I have two variables. The first variable is binary (yes or no) and measures if a person is happy or not. The second variable consists of 5 integers from 1 to 5 and measures if an emotion is positive or negative. For example, a 1 means negative emotion and a 5 means very positive emotion. I'm not sure if this variable is categorical or ordinal. In total I have 10'000 measures for each variable.

I would like to calculate the correlation between these two variables. Which is the best measure? Is it Pearson correlation?

Comment: I'd certainly call your variable ordinal, not categorical.

Comment: But do you know if this second variable is "at least" ordinal? So ordinal or better?

Comment: @KaPy3141 What do you mean by better than ordinal?

Comment: @machinery: Ordinal means that the values inherently have a sorted nature, but they are not necessarily on a (linear or any) scale. For example the difference between the 3rd and 4th element might be way bigger than the difference between the 4th and 1000th element. So when you say you are not sure whether the values are ordinal, then do you count "better than ordinal" still as ordinal?

Comment: @KaPy3141 The values are probably not numerical. Although I have integer values from 1 to 5 and the difference between them is always 1, I don't know if the "real" difference is also 1. That means for somebody the difference between a 4 (positive) and a 5 (very positive) could be bigger than the difference between a 1 (very negative) and a 2 (negative). If that is the case is the variable then "only" ordinal? Or is it numerical because the differences are always 1?

Comment: That's an ordinal variable. You could have labeled them  negative, slightly negative, neutral, positive, and very positive, and your analysis would be the same.

Comment: @Dave Alright, so should I pick Spearman or Pearson correlation for an ordinal variable versus a binary variable?

Comment: In that case, if they are for sure at least ordinal, then a Spearman/Pearson Correlation or or Chi-Square test would make sense! You could even use a T-test, as in this case, it would basically test whether the slope is 0, hence it tests a correlation.

Comment: Ordinal scale is a "quantitative categorical" one. It is categorical because it is not metric (nor count). Still, it is quantitative, not nominal.